# Eigen space of $T^*T$ and singular value of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $T$ is an $n$ by $n$ complex non-singular matrix. Then singular values of $T$ are positive square root of the eigen values of the matrix $T^*T$. Therefore for each sigular value $\sigma$ of $T$, $\sigma^2$ corresponds an eigen space $H(T)_{\sigma^2}$ of $T^*T$, say.

It is also well-known that for $\sigma$ is a sigular value of $T$, $\frac{1}{\sigma}$ is a singular value of $T^{-1}$. My questions are:

Is $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ an eigen value of $(TT^*)^{-1}$? Moreover, is there any relation between the eigen spaces $H(T)_{\sigma^2}$ and $H(T^{-1})_{\frac{1}{\sigma^2}}$

Another question (not related to this) is if $U$ is an unitary operator identified as a matrix acting on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space $K$, then is the restriction of $U$ on some subspace of $K$ unitary?

Comment: $\frac 1{\sigma^2}$ is an eigenvalue of $(TT^*)^{-1} = T^{-*}T^{-1}$, just as $\sigma^2$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*T$.

Comment: Thank you!Can you shed some light about relation between their eigen spaces@BenGrossmann

Comment: For any invertible matrix $A$, $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have the same eigenevectors. With that, we see that $TT^*$ and its inverse $T^{-*}T^{-1}$ have the same eigenvectors, as do $T^*T$ and $T^{-1}T^{-*}$. Notably, $TT^*$ and $T^*T$ have the same eigenvalues (but not necessarily the same eigenvectors).